# Avoid concurrent execution of Akka actor

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm currently sending a message to an Akka actor every second for it to perform a task.

If that task (function) is still running when a new message is received by the actor, I would like the actor to do nothing. Basically, I want the actor function to be run only if it's not already running.

What's a good way to do this? Should I use Akka actors or do it another way?

Cheers

Comment: If the function is being run synchronously inside of the actor it will already behave like that. It has a message box and will only ever process a single message at a time.

Comment: @drexin Not exactly. The question seems to imply that the message should be dropped if the actor is busy. (But this is a bad use case for actors. Actors are not supposed to take significant lengths of time to process a message.)

Comment: @Blackbird You want to prevent interfering new message processing if actor is already processing some message? Or you want to pause/abort current processing when new message arrives?

Comment: I don't want the current processing to be aborted. I want the message to be ignored if the last message is still being processed. @RobinGreen is right.

Comment: I'm a pre-newbie, but I wonder if the actor might be able to dequeue() everything in the actor's mailbox's MessageQueue when it finishes processing a message.  I believe that has the effect you desire, except perhaps that messages may pile up if it takes many seconds to execute.  There may be architectural reasons this is a bad idea; it definitely seems like behavior that's beyond the envisioned scope of an Actor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actors process a message at a time. The situation you describe cannot happen.

Comment: But in case of processing such messages for more than 1 second there can be possible mailbox overflow with OOME.

Comment: @SergiyPrydatchenko unless you're using bounded mailbox, nope?

Comment: @om-nom-nom Of course you can use bounded mailbox if sender thread blocking is ok for your application.

Comment: Have the processor ask for work or acknowledge performed work before sending it new messages

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the OP was just a little sloppy in their language; where `...is received by the actor...` was intended to mean `...is received by the mailbox of the actor...`.

Comment: Good point! "Received by the mailbox" is not a useful distinction as the message can be in flight X time before it lands in the mailbox. (Remoting et al)

Comment: Alright, I accepted that answer because I didn't know enough about actors before posting. Now I know that what I want is to avoid mailbox overflow. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Akka actors process their messages asynchronously one-by-one, so you can only drop/ignore "expired" messages to avoid extra processing and OutOfMemoryException-s due to actor's Mailbox overflow.

You can ignore expired (more than 1 second old in your case) messages inside your actor:

```
case class DoWork(createdTime: Long = System.currentTimeMillis)

final val messageTimeout = 1000L // one second

def receive = {
  case DoWork(createdTime) =>
    if((System.currentTimeMillis - createdTime) < messageTimeout) { doWork() }    
}
```

Or you can create a custom Mailbox which can drop expired messages internally.

Of course, as Robin Green already mentioned, actors in general are not supposed to run long-running operations internally so this approach can be suitable only if your actor doesn't need to process other kind of messages (they will not be processed in time). And in case of high CPU demands you may consider to move your actor on a separate dispatcher.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "expired" messages, sorry.

Comment: If you send a message to an actor every second and if your actor receives a message from its mailbox that has been sent (created) more than a second ago this will mean that this message has been stored in the mailbox for more than a second (while your actor was busy with processing previous one) - so you can safely discard this message (if it doesn't contain important data of course) and wait for the next message which should be received within a second.

Comment: @om-nom-nom You're right - for remote actors will be better to drop extra messages directly from the mailbox (based on the number of messages in the mailbox or their receive time).